# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: sh: 1: glxinfo:

Tags: android-virtual-device, android-7.0-nougat

Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: sh: 1: glxinfo: not found Could not launch '.../sdk/tools/qemu/linux-x86/qem u-system-i386': No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: try this may be it help http://stackoverflow.com/a/37679624/5305430

Answer (score 33):

You need to install the tool.  On Ubuntu you can do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Comment: thanks a lot~
root cause...not found Could not launch '.../sdk/tools/qemu/linux-x86/

Comment: Weird, I was able to launch AVD before, but today I wasn't able to until I installed `mesa-utils`.