# Cannot start Emulator in android studio 2.0

Tags: android

I just upgraded my android studio from 1.5 to 2.0.And now I am facing some weird bug when I try to start Emulator. I use Ubuntu 15.10 OS

Android monitor returns this message

```
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range    for  operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  33
Current serial number in output stream:  34
 QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

When I was using 1.5 version all was going good. Is it a bug in android studio 2.0.

How to remove this error?

Comment: @greywolf82 but how could it be not there.. just 6 hrs back android studio 1.5 was working good with emulator...hows this possible?

Comment: Because the old emulator was working in a really different way. The new emulator works with qemu and opengl

Comment: @greywolf82 that means I need to install this softwares ?

Comment: No it means you need to upgrade your OS and maybe change your graphic card.

Comment: @greywolf82 upgrading os is not possible..because I am using recent version...how do I change graphic card..any idea?

Comment: How? Buy a new one, open your case and change the board.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot launch emulator on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Verify that you have installed in your system lib64stdc++6

With a 32 bits operating system :

```
# apt-get install lib64stdc++6
```

With a 64 bits operating system with multiarch enabled :

```
# apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
```

Then link the new installed libraries to the android sdk tools path

```
$ cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

EDIT: in `15.10 x64` with current Sdk (23), the folder is `$ANDROID_HOME/Sdk`

Comment: UPVOTED!  worked like a charm.  NOTE FOR NEWBIES: `$ANDROID_HOME` is the path from your system's root to the folder where Android is contained in.  for example: `\home\tony\Android`

Comment: hey same problem with me and when i using `cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++` command its give me this  `bash: cd: /android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++: No such file or directory` please help.

Comment: @sushildlh you have to replace `$ANDROID_HOME` with your real android sdk installation path. Then the rest of the path should be as in the reply per default, otherwise change it accordingly to your.

Comment: For newer users of Android Studio my file path changed slightly in this case being `home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++`

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 16.04 over ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++

Comment: UPVOTED ! BTW for Android Source build nougat (JDK8) path is different

apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386

cd ~/ANDROID_HOME/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++        

mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak       

ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/ANDROID_HOME/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Doing a 'sudo apt install mesa-utils' was what fixed the issue for me (search this page for mesa-utils).

Comment: Just a workaround in my case the path was /home/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/libstdc++ long live ubuntu

Comment: You saved me so much @cammando on Android Studio 3 I searched for $ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/tools/lib64 and could't see that folder.

Comment: While this worked many times, and still works, it can't be the only solution after so many years. Surely someone from Android Dev Team looked into this problem and tried to solve it, or is there reason why it is not solved yet, why it can't work out of the box ??

Comment: works good. my path was: `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++`

Comment: Find your path with `find $ANDROID_HOME -name "libstdc++"`

Answer (score 25):

Another solution for me was to use systems libraries:

`emulator -use-system-libs -avd YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE_NAME`

Comment: okay I havent tested this ans... but one suggestion when you ans which contains Some variable in the command.. Try using UPPERCASE letter. since it is good pratice to use.. thanks for your ans

Comment: How can I launch emulator from UI with this option? I am too lazy to start emulator from terminal each time (:

Comment: You could make it into a gradle task that runs that command. And then you can run it from the Gradle tab or using Run Configuration on the top bar.

Comment: try to go yours way, but catch a mistake: `sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
[139650585499456]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Looks like you have some missing libraries. Try with the selected answer instead, or something like the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258908/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-output-sh-1-glxinfo depending on your OS

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue on an Arch Linux box. I had to do two things to solve all the issues:

1. Install `mesa-demos`. This is the Arch Linux package which contains `glxinfo`:

   ```
   $ sudo pacman -S mesa-demos
   ```
2. Run the emulator with the `-use-system-libs` flag:

   ```
   $ emulator -avd <AVD name> -use-system-libs
   ```

   To enable this behavior in Android Studio, I set the `ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS` enviornment variable in `~/.zshrc`.

   ```
   export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
   ```

   You can also set this in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. In all of these cases, you will have to start Android Studio from the command-line. Alternatively, you can set it in `~/.pam_environment` to be able to start Android Studio from a desktop launcher:

   ```
   ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
   ```

Comment: This should be the best answer (supposing that the system lib required is installed) as you don't mess around with the software contents itself.

Comment: Yes. Note that you can lists your AVDs with `emulator -list-avds`

Answer (score 16):

After doing the two steps above (posted by Giorgio Ghiatis), install mesa-utils if it is not installed.

$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

Comment: What do you mean by above ?

Comment: The steps posted by Giorgio Ghiatis

Answer (score 13):

```
$ cd Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

it's worked for me

Comment: This did it for me, android studio 3.0.1 on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: I was having trouble finding the lib64 path. This worked!

Answer (score 9):

Same problem for me on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64** with :

- Android Studio 2.2.3
- Android SDK Tools 25.2.4
- Emulator version 25.2.4-3534729 (From Emulator > Extended Controls > Help > About)

My graphic card is an AMD/ATI Radeon and I read from [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197254) on Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker that :

> The root cause of the problem is likely that the Radeon GL driver
>   library requires a more recent libstdc++.so than the one bundled with
>   the emulator.

**Here's how I fixed the problem :**

1. Install lib64stdc++6

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
   ```
2. Install mesa-demos

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
   ```
3. Move libstdc++.so.6 out of the way by renaming it to libstdc++.so.6.bak

   ```
   $ cd ~/$ANDROID_HOME/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
   $ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
   ```

Comment: These steps worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you for providing them. I find it strange that their official installation instructions currently tell you to install the wrong libraries.

Comment: These Steps worked for me on Android Studio 2.2.3 using Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04 step 1 and 3 worked fine (without step 2)

Answer (score 2):

after the update to build tools 25.3.1 `libstdc++.so.6` file had been moved to `$ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 1):

In an extraordinary situation your KVM resources might be busy because of another running VirtualBox VMs.

(I've experienced this issue).

To overcome this issue I used Genymotion instead of Android Emulator.

Then I could run Genymotion together with other VirtualBox VMs.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++ 
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

**Fix on Ubuntu 16 LTS**

*1.Install lib64stdc++6*

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
```

*2.Install mesa-demos*

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Ref: https://github.com/beidl/prime-indicator/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers did not work for me as "Android Emulator" was not installed with standard installation of Android Studio. Make sure you have installed it and then try above answers.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution didn't work for me.

The solution that work for me was telling to Android Studio that use the system libraries instead of the built-in by editing $HOME/.profile and adding the next line:  `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1`, and then re-log.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new AVD, or edit an existing one and change the **Emulated Performance Graphics** from Automatic to **Software**

[image]