# Android Virtual Device not Starting up with Linux

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am working at Android Studio but when I click the start emulator the emulator gives me that error:

```
 sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
    sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
    qemu: hardware error: Can't set isa irqs with no isa bus present.
    CPU #0:
    EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000663
    ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
    EIP=0000fff0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
    ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
    SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
    TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
    GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
    IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
    CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
    DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
    DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
    EFER=0000000000000000
    FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
    FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
    XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
    CPU #1:
    EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000663
    ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
    EIP=0000fff0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=1
    ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
    SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
    LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
    TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
    GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
    IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
    CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
    DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
    DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
    EFER=0000000000000000
    FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
    FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
    FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
    XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
    XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

I installed nvdia drivers.

My device settings-> 
[Device setting1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT7Gu.png)

[Device setting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zztbs.png)
And these studio shows me that settings:

```
Name: Nexus_4_API_24

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /home/ncelik/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_24.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 24)

Skin: nexus_4

SD Card: /home/ncelik/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_24.avd/sdcard.img

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 4

vm.heapSize: 512

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 24

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-24/google_apis/x86/

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_4_API_24

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 320

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 4 API 24

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: post your emulator settings

Comment: i editted my question

Comment: is your HAXM updated?

Comment: i can not install HAXM because SDK manager say to me 'the HAXM isn't compatible with linux'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start Emulator in android studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554322/cannot-start-emulator-in-android-studio-2-0)