# Doesn't start android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, simulator

```
03/05 23:18:20: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

I am trying to run simple helloworld application, but simulator doesnt want to work :(
What is wrong? Lubuntu 16.10, android studio 2.3, nexus 5 api 19/22, nexus 5x api 22.

Comment: This may be caused by many things. Please provide more information about your AVD configuration.

Comment: It is default configuration of devises.
For example, Nexus 5x: android 7.0, api lvl 24, cpu x86

Comment: Which system image?

Answer (score 1):

Remove or rename the directory

```
Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

Answer (score 0):

I once solved this problem by changing the filename of `libstdc++.so.6` to `libstdc++.so.6.bak` in the directory `Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++`, as described in [Cannot start Emulator in android studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554322/cannot-start-emulator-in-android-studio-2-0). (I found that installing `lib64stdc++6:i386` didn't help for this problem but for the failed-to-create-sd-card problem, that `mesa-utils` was already installed in Ubuntu by default, and that it was not necessary to create a hard link.) However, it seems that in the latest Android Studio 2.3, the `libstdc++.so.6` file has been moved to `Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++`, so simply go to that directory and change the filename of `libstdc++.so.6`, and everything should be OK.